# When sorting a list, Should the type of list used determine which sorting algorithm to choose

Tags: sorting, arraylist, linked-list

Are certain sorting algorithms better for sorting ArrayLists, vice versa with linked lists

Comment: Yes. I can't think of a good book discussing this right now, but at least if you google "sorting algorithm array or linked list" you will find several pages about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for arrays, you can use quick sort or merge sort (in some cases radix sort).

For linked lists, a bottom up merge sort using a small (26 to 32) array of lists (or optionally iterators), is the most efficient, but since nodes in a large list may be scattered, then every node access may involve a cache miss. Typically it is faster to copy the list to an array, do an array based sort, then create a sorted list from the array. Wiki pseudo-code for bottom up merge sort for linked list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @trincot - missed an edit. Answer updated now.